# Plotting a function of two variables in R using plotFun

Tags: r, function, plot

I am trying to plot a function of two variables in RStudio. I used the following code:

```
plotFun(-110.90+0.156*x+51.09*y-0.04*x*y ~ x & y,
        x.lim=range(0,10),
        y.lim=range(0,10),
        surface=TRUE)
```

It gave an error saying could not find function `plotFun`. I tried the same code outside RStudio in R console but got the same error. Can anybody provide some hint why this is happening?

Comment: There is no function called `plotFun` - it exists in the *mosaic* package which you need to install and then load with `library(mosaic)`

Comment: @thelatemail I tried installing the mosaic package using command install.packages("mosaic") in RStudio but I got following errors: like "unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Comment: Try a different CRAN mirror or wait a minute. The site might be down.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the R tutorial over the internet and I came across the same problem. The solution is to install the library
**mosaic** You can do so by simple command on the R console:

```
install.packages('mosaic')
```